# JQuery client side continues even if invalid mvc 4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict";
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#form"));
$("#submit").on("click", function () {
    var form = $("#form");
    form.validate();
    if (form.valid()) {
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

**HTML**

```
        <span>Please enter the amount of orders you wish you process:</span>
    <br>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderModel.AmountOfOrders, new {id = "AmountOfOrders"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.OrderModel.AmountOfOrders)

    <input type="submit" value ="Submit" id="submit" />
```

I seem to have a problem with the script. The DataAnnotations for C# are showing up on the View but even if required fields are empty it will still continue to the other page.

Comment: What is `"use strict"` doing there?

Comment: What do you mean " it will still continue to the other page", the JS you have posted does not navigate anywhere, it simply calls some validation methods then returns false, regardless of the outcome of the validation.

Comment: Please show your HTML as well so any other problems can be spotted :)

Comment: the "use strict" was added when I was doing somethings with JLint, you can ignore that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your button is not given

```
type="button"
```

, it will default to

```
type="submit"
```

Considering that you are using a form, the form will get submitted by the button click as your javascript is executing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#submit").on("click", function (event) {
    var form = $("#form");
    form.validate();
if (form.valid()) {
}
else
{
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;

}
});
```

Comment: `return false` does both `event.preventDefault()` *and* `event.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 0):

Always use the `submit` event for forms, not the `click` event. That way it will work with key-presses:

```
$("#submit").on("submit", function () {
    var form = $("#form");
    form.validate();
    if (form.valid()) {
        // Proceed with submit!
    }
    else {
        // Stop submit!
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I suspect the OP does not have a form with an `id="submit"`, "use strict" is valid, it turns strict mode on in the scope of the function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode.

Comment: @Ben Robinson: Thanks for clarifying that. Very ugly syntax :)